# Scalaz: what role does filter play in |@|?

Tags: scala, scalaz, monad-transformers

We used the WriterT monad transformer on Futures hoping to get more organized logs from an asynchronous application, but we ran into some trouble.

If I compile the application below, I get the following error. Please note that this isn't the warning about withFilter.

> [error] value filter is not a member of scalaz.WriterT[scala.concurrent.Future,List[String],String]

Why does |@| need filter here? Does Scalaz provide an implicit conversion for this case?

```
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
import scala.concurrent.Future
import scalaz._
import Scalaz._

object Failure extends App {

  type LoggedT[F[_], A] = WriterT[F, List[String], A]
  type LoggedFuture[A] = LoggedT[Future, A]

  //this is the applicative behavior that we want WriterT to preserve
  val example = for {
    z <- (Future("left") |@| Future("right")) { (x: String, y: String) => x + " " + y }
  } yield z

  example.onSuccess { case x => println(x) }

  val test = for {
    z: String <- (Future("left").liftM[LoggedT] |@| Future("right").liftM[LoggedT]) { (x: String, y: String) => x + " " + y }
  } yield z

  test.value.onSuccess { case x => println(x) }

}
```

The error occurs with Scala version: 2.11.7 and Scalaz version: 7.2.0

Answer (score 7):

It's often convenient to use the reflection library's `reify` to see what's happening during desugaring (this is the only time I'd ever suggest importing anything from `scala.reflect.runtime`, and even in this case only in the REPL during development):

```
scala> import scala.reflect.runtime.universe.reify
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe.reify

scala> reify(for { x: Int <- Option(1) } yield x)
res5: reflect.runtime.universe.Expr[Option[Int]] =
Expr[scala.Option[Int]](Option.apply(1).withFilter(((check$ifrefutable$1) => check$ifrefutable$1: @unchecked match {
  case (x @ (_: Int)) => true
  case _ => false
})).map(((x: Int) => x)))
```

The problem is the type-case pattern match in the *for*-comprehension. Even though the compiler will verify that the match is safe (e.g. `for { x: String <- Option(1) } yield x` won't compile), it's still desugared to a filtering operation. I'm not sure why—there's probably a reason for it, and there's even a small chance that it's a good reason.

You get a message about `filter` because that's the compiler's last resort in this case. First it will try to desugar to a call to `withFilter`, and if it doesn't find a `withFilter`, it'll use `filter` (which at least in the collection library's implementations is generally less efficient in cases like this). In the case of `WriterT` it finds neither (since filtering a writer doesn't make sense in the general case), so it complains about the last one it tried.

The solution is just not to use type-case matching. Write a plain old `for { z <- ... } yield z` and everything will work just fine. In fact [I'd suggest not ever using type-case matching](https://twitter.com/travisbrown/status/453129047829397504)—it's the sneakiest way for runtime reflection-related problems to end up in your code. In this case the operation will be checked at compile-time (at least in the obvious cases), but it's still unnecessary and potentially less efficient.